# coldfusion input type = 'hidden' not hiding

Tags: input, coldfusion, hidden, cfml

I have a form which is passing variables and there are lots of hidden inputs in it, followed by a submit.  Here is a some code:

```
<input type = "hidden" name =  "templname" value =  '#templname#'>
<input type = "hidden" name =  "attloc"    value = '#extattloc#'>      
 <input type = "hidden" name =  "cctype"    value = 'f'>
 <input type = "hidden" name =  "merls"     value = '#merls#'>
  <input type = "hidden" name =  "invnum"    value = '#invnum#'>

  <cfif ArrayIsDefined(selvalarr,1)>
        <cfloop array = "#selvalarr#" index = "att"> 
           <input type = "hidden" name = "att" value ="#att#">
        </cfloop>
   </cfif>

   <cfloop array = "#letarr#" index = "let">
    <input type = "hidden" name =  "let" value = '#let#'>
   </cfloop>

     <input type   = "submit" 
           class   = 'repbutton onoffbut'  
           style   = 'height:75px;'             
           id      = "runemail"                             
           value   = "run email"  >
  </form>
  </td>
```

Everything is what you'd expect -- except for the loop on letarr.  The variable #let# is being dumped onto the page, although the input is clearly hidden. Here is what the variable "let" looks like (2 values).  This output was from the following code:

```
<cfloop array = "#letarr#" index = "let">
<br>#let#     
</cfloop>
```

[image]

Here is what the hidden input gives me:

[image]

Nothing should be there except the 'run email' button.

I've done a straight output of the array "letarr", and it is correct (see above).  I've checked that having it inside a `<td` tag is not the problem.  I think it's something about the variable, perhaps the multiple lines.

Does anyone out there have an idea what is causing this?  or how to fix it?

Comment: Could this be to do with the single quotes that you're wrapping `#let#` into: `value='#let#'>`.  Is the value of the parameter HTML encoded so that if it contains HTML characters it won't break the output?  Does it contain single\double quotes?

Comment: I've used both single and double quotes -- it makes no difference.  There are no quotes in the output, although that is something I'd better watch out for.  It's certainly possible that there is html code inside that variable.  How would I encode the parameter HTML?

Comment: Do a search on ColdFusion encode for HTML

Comment: Thanks guys. The encoding solved the immediate problem.  I wasn't researching XSS attacks, so I wouldn't have known about this.  I have to do something with the form fields once passed thru, and I'll see whether this gets me what I need.  But glad to learn about encoding for HTML regardless.

Answer (score 5):

Do a couple of steps.

1. Do a `<cfdump var="#letarr#">` to make sure there are no unexpected values.
2. Make sure to protect the variables from injections

   ```
   <cfloop array = "#letarr#" index = "let">
     <input type = "hidden" name =  "let" value = '#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(let)#'>
   </cfloop>
   ```
3. I really wonder if there is a missing quote or a strange thing that looks like a quote in your string. I would look for a back tick, a smart(aka dumb) quote, and accent mark or something. Your results look like it gave up on HTML somewhere

Comment: There could well have been some kind of quote in the HTML.  The EncodeForHTML solved the immediate problem of not sending thru the hidden input.  Unfortunately I did not get the results I wanted on the receiving page. I'll try EncodeForHTMLAttribute and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use `encodeForHTML()` to avoid issues like these.

Comment: I think you wanted to say `encodeforHTMLAttribute()`